# How to put a subcaption inside a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have put a few images inside a tikzpicture. Now I want to add a subcaption for each of them. How is this possible? I also tried `\captionof` which didn't work either.

**Minimum not working example:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
asdf
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\node (a){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node [below= of a]{\subcaption{hello}\label{subfig:hi}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:captionlabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are loading package `subcaption`, why don't you use it? You don't need tikz at all to do hat you want.

Comment: Because the real image is much more complex.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the image is the image, the caption is the caption. A caption should never be in a tikzpicture.

Comment: I like the code reduction capability of tikz  `foreach` to arrange all figures in a loop, instead of opening 8 subfigures. Why not use it if `\captionof` is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either use `text width` as the node option or use a `\parbox` (or `minipage`) so that the `\captionof` is inside a group.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
asdf
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt] (a){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node [below= 1ex of a.south,inner sep=0pt]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\captionof{subfigure}{hello\label{subfig:hi}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:captionlabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charme! The only drawback is that the subcaptions are linked to the previous figure. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: @fmetz: Sorry I don't understand. How they are linked to previous image?

Comment: because the figure caption is declared after the tikzpicture, the subcaptions are referenced as 4.4a, 4.4b instead of 4.5a, 4.5b if the current figure is 4.5

Comment: @fmetz: Generally the subfigures won't be displayed as 1.5a` but just `a`. Can you show the code that does this?

Comment: I mean if you do a \ref{subfig:abc} in text.

Comment: @fmetz: You may add `\refstepcounter{figure}` after `\centering` and then `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before `\caption{caption}`. I don't know your use cases but this kind of is unusual and frowned upon :)

Comment: Haha this is awful :D

Comment: @fmetz Why :). Does it work?

Comment: Yeah it works! Beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Simple \texttt{tikz} picture}
\label{fig:TikzSimple}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{subfig:SubfigureLeft}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \caption{Another subfigure}
        \label{subfig:SubfigureRight}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Example from the \texttt{subcaption} manual, page 5}
    \label{fig:SubfigureManuel}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        %
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \filldraw[red] (0,0) circle (3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %
        \caption{A subfigure}
        \label{subfig:CombinationLeft}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        %
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle (3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %
        \caption{Another subfigure}
        \label{subfig:CombinationRight}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Combination of \figurename~\ref{fig:TikzSimple} and \ref{fig:SubfigureManuel}.}
    \label{fig:Combination}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: That's a tikz picture into a subcaption, not a subcaption into a tikz picture.