# How to add caption to graphics defined this way

Tags: graphics, captions

I found this code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218378/forcing-subfigures-to-have-same-height-and-take-overall-x-of-linewidth-in-latex) since it's exactly what I need to use, but also I need a caption under both of them. There is an example for a subcaption but that's not it. I simply tried to add the caption command but it doesn't work.
Can someone tell me how to modify it?
Thanks.

```
 \begin{center}
   \resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{
   \includegraphics[height=3cm]{pic1}
 % \caption{Picture 1}
   \label{fig:pic1}
\quad
   \includegraphics[height=3cm]{pic2}
 % \caption{Picture 2}
   \label{fig:pic2}
 }
\end{center}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275852 and/or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361579

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal code example (not just a code fragment with pictures that people cannot access). For dummy pictures, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738.

Comment: Just use \captionof{figure}{...} from the caption or captionof packages.  The center environment is as good as anything.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` see if use package `float` and positioning option `H` in `begin{figure}[H] ... \end{figure}` is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic1}
   \caption{Picture 1}
\label{fig:pic1}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic2}
   \caption{Picture 2}
\label{fig:pic2}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{caption for both figure}
\label{fig:1-2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]