Add smaller captions or make them separated in parts
Excuse if the title is confusing, I'm working on my first LateX document and I am wondering how or if it would be possible to add separate captions to these karnaugh maps to avoid confusion. Currently I just have one caption saying what the K-maps are consisting off but it comes across as very confusing as I haven't titled the K-maps themselves.
My current setup looks as following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{K-map for $J_2$, $K_2$, $J_1$, $K_1$, $J_0$ och $K_0$}
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{2}
        \maxterms{1}
        \terms{0,3,4,5,6,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{3}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}\hfill 
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{6}
        \maxterms{4}
        \terms{0,1,2,3,5,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{3}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}

    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{1,4}
        \terms{0,2,3,5,6,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}\hfill 
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{2,6}
        \terms{0,1,3,4,5,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}

    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{6}
        \maxterms{2,4}
        \terms{0,1,3,5,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{7}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}\hfill 
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
        \minterms{1}
        \terms{0,2,3,4,5,6,7}{$X$}
        \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
\end {figure}

\end{document}



Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Many thanks! I looked through the post you attached, hopefully it is all touched up now...

Guess: You are searching for package subcaption as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383256/277964 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275857/277964

You can use subcaption, for example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{position=above}% because you are using \setminus{caption} above the content
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{K-map for $J_2$, $K_2$, $J_1$, $K_1$, $J_0$ och $K_0$}
  \subcaptionbox{$J_2$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{2}
      \maxterms{1}
      \terms{0,3,4,5,6,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{3}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{$K_2$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{6}
      \maxterms{4}
      \terms{0,1,2,3,5,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{3}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }
  \subcaptionbox{$J_1$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{1,4}
      \terms{0,2,3,5,6,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{$K_1$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{2,6}
      \terms{0,1,3,4,5,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }
  \subcaptionbox{$J_0$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{6}
      \maxterms{2,4}
      \terms{0,1,3,5,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{7}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{$K_0$}{%
    \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][2][1][$q_0$][$q_1$][$q_2$]
      \minterms{1}
      \terms{0,2,3,4,5,6,7}{$X$}
      \implicant{0}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}

to get:

Sorry, I do not know, which sub-figure is which one, so the sub-captions are only a guess. Feel free to correct them.
The formatting of the sub-captions can be done with the interface of package caption. So I recommend to not only read the subcaption manual but also the caption manual. For example, to move the sub-captions below the images, use
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below}

or to make them smaller use:
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}


Thanks a lot! That makes a lot of sense, I didn't realise that was a tool up for disposal. LateX truly is amazing!
